# What are all the subgroups of $C_m \rtimes C_n$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> What are all the subgroups of $C_m \rtimes C_n$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

As we know for $n=2$ it is isomorphic to dihedral group of order $2m$ whose all subgroups are [known](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf). But, in general, I am unable to find them.

Comment: With $C_n$ you mean the cyclic group with $n$ element? As you are interessted in the semidirect products you first have to find all the automorphisms on $C_m$. Those are the units of the multiplicative group. But a classification of all subgroups of some non abelian group doesn't seem to be that easy at all

Comment: @DominicMichaelis yes, $C_n$ is cyclic group of order $n$. Should I try to find answer by taking some particular cases?